# Replace for-loop with alrorithm (c++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop

i'm new to c++ and i'm facing the following problem:

I have the following for-loop within a function:

```
bool PlayerSea::allShipsDestroyed() const
{
    bool destroyed = true;
    for (auto const & ship : ships) {
        if (!ship.isDestroyed()) {
            destroyed = false;
        }
    }
    return destroyed;
}
```

This function checks if every ship (there are 3 for each player) is destroyed by going over the vector and setting "destroyed" to false if a ship is not destroyed yet. This is done by calling the "isDestroyed()" function:

```
bool Ship::isDestroyed() const
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        Coordinates coordinates = (orientation == Sea::Orientation::X) ? Coordinates(x + i, y) : Coordinates(x, y + i);
        if (!wasHitAt(coordinates)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now this is my attempt to replace the for-loop above with a loop done with alrogithms:

```
bool destroyed = true;
auto foundPosition = std::for_each(ships.begin(), ships.end(), ships);
if (foundPosition != ship.isDestroyed()) {
    destroyed = false;
}
return destroyed;
```

Besides that I guess that its wrong, my compiler throws the following error:

```
>------ Build started: Project: CMakeLists, Configuration: Debug ------
  [1/3] Building CXX object src\libGameObjects\CMakeFiles\GameObjects.dir\PlayerSea.cpp.obj
  FAILED: src/libGameObjects/CMakeFiles/GameObjects.dir/PlayerSea.cpp.obj 
  C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.300\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP  -I..\..\..\src\libGameObjects -I..\..\..\src\libSea /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -MDd /W4 -std:c++17 /showIncludes /Fosrc\libGameObjects\CMakeFiles\GameObjects.dir\PlayerSea.cpp.obj /Fdsrc\libGameObjects\CMakeFiles\GameObjects.dir\GameObjects.pdb /FS -c ..\..\..\src\libGameObjects\PlayerSea.cpp
C:\Users\janbe\Source\Repos\Gruppe_1C4\blatt8\src\libGameObjects\PlayerSea.cpp(135): error C2065: 'ship': undeclared identifier
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I am aware that i'm still a noob, please be kind! Apparently I didn't find a answer to my question online, or at least i didnt find one that is simple enough for me to understand. Maybe someone could give me a hint? :)

Comment: Hello, as you can see in the error returned by the compiler: `'ship': undeclared identifier`, you do not declare the `ship` variable in your second code. In the first code, the `ship` variable was declared in the loop with `auto const & ship`

Comment: Once you've found a ship that isn't "destroyed" you don't need to loop any more and can return `false` directly. If all ship were "destroyed" then you can return `true`. With that said, `std::all_of` ([as shown in MikeCAT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68161995/440558)) is a much better solution.

Comment: Also note that while your attempt using `std::for_each` and the `std::all_of` solution removes your explicit loop, there's still a loop inside those functions. If you want to avoid looping altogether then that's not really possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want to check if all ships are destroyed, so you should use [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

```
bool destroyed = std::all_of(ships.begin(), ships.end(),
    [](const Ship& ship){ return ship.isDestroyed(); });
```

Comment: Or `std::mem_fn(&Ship::isDestroyed)` instead of the lambda

Comment: C++11 and later (which is implied by the OP, due to using a range-based `for`) it may be preferable to use `std::begin(ships)` and `std::end(ships)`.   That makes it general to any container, as well as raw arrays.

Comment: @MikeCAT Could you explain the "  [](const Ship& ship){ return ship.isDestroyed(); });" part please? I think I made the whole thing working by: 

      `bool destroyed = true;
       destroyed = std::all_of(ships.begin(), ships.end(),
       [](const Ship& ship) { return ship.isDestroyed(); });
        return destroyed;`

Looks like i needed destroyed to be initialized as true as in the example above and then return the value destroyed because the compiler needs a return value that is not within the loop somehow. Am I wrong?

Comment: @NeroTheDawn Yes, I think you are wrong. You won't need to initialize `destroyed` before the assignment because the assignment will overwrite the value of `destroyed` and its previous value won't affect the result of the assignment. Also in this case you even won't need the variable `destroyed` and can directly return the result of `std::all_of`.

Comment: So like: `return std::all_of(ships.begin(), ships.end(),
            [](const Ship& ship) { return ship.isDestroyed(); });`

Comment: @NeroTheDawn Yes. `[](const Ship& ship) { return ship.isDestroyed(); }` is a *lambda function*. It is like a function that takes one argument `ship` and returns `ship.isDestroyed()`.

Comment: @MikeCAT But won't that return "true" if a single ship is destroyed? I mean it has to set destroyed as false if there is a single ship l iving and only to true if every single ship is destroyed (or directly return false/true). Maybe I have an error in thinking but i'm not sure

Comment: @NeroTheDawn It looks unclear what you mean. [Try it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kYy2NQORrAHz1mKe).

Comment: I really had an error in my thinking. I thought that the solution you send sends back a "true" for "ships.destroyed" if a single ship is destroyed which would be wrong because we only can return a true when EVERY ship is destroyed. But as your solution is checking every single ship  that exists to be destroyed, it should be fine. Or at least, as I tried, it works now! thank you so much <3